# Problems trying to decrease player size in Minecraft Forge 1.16.5

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to develop a mod for minecraft, my first time creating mods, and I'm having a really hard time getting the player to be the permanent size of a block

```
//PlayerScaleHandler:

package com.example.hollowknightmod;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraftforge.api.distmarker.Dist;
import net.minecraftforge.api.distmarker.OnlyIn;
import net.minecraftforge.client.event.RenderPlayerEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;

import com.mojang.blaze3d.matrix.MatrixStack;

@Mod.EventBusSubscriber(modid = HollowKnightMod.MOD_ID, value = Dist.CLIENT)
public class PlayerScaleHandler {

    private static final float BLOCK_SIZE_SCALE = 0.5f; // Exemplo: escala pela metade (0.5)

    @OnlyIn(Dist.CLIENT)
    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void onRenderPlayer(RenderPlayerEvent.Pre event) {
        if (event.getPlayer() != null && event.getPlayer() == Minecraft.getInstance().player) {
            MatrixStack matrixStack = event.getMatrixStack();
            matrixStack.pushPose();

            float currentScale = BLOCK_SIZE_SCALE;
            matrixStack.scale(currentScale, currentScale, currentScale);

        }
    }
}


//MainClass:


package com.example.hollowknightmod;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.Blocks;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.event.RegistryEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.IEventBus;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.InterModComms;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLClientSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLCommonSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.InterModEnqueueEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.InterModProcessEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.server.FMLServerStartingEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLJavaModLoadingContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;


import java.util.stream.Collectors;

// The value here should match an entry in the META-INF/mods.toml file
@Mod(HollowKnightMod.MOD_ID)
public class HollowKnightMod
{
    // Directly reference a log4j logger.
    public static final String MOD_ID = "hollowknightmod";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();


    public HollowKnightMod() {
        // Register the setup method for modloading

        IEventBus eventBus = FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus();

        ModBlocks.register(eventBus);
        ModItems.register(eventBus);

        ModSoundEvents.register(eventBus);


        eventBus.addListener(this::setup);
        // Register the enqueueIMC method for modloading
        eventBus.addListener(this::enqueueIMC);
        // Register the processIMC method for modloading
        eventBus.addListener(this::processIMC);
        // Register the doClientStuff method for modloading
        eventBus.addListener(this::doClientStuff);

        // Register ourselves for server and other game events we are interested in
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
    }

    private void setup(final FMLCommonSetupEvent event)
    {
        // some preinit code
        LOGGER.info("HELLO FROM PREINIT");
        LOGGER.info("DIRT BLOCK >> {}", Blocks.DIRT.getRegistryName());
    }

    private void doClientStuff(final FMLClientSetupEvent event) {
        // do something that can only be done on the client
        FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().register(PlayerScaleHandler.class);
        LOGGER.info("Got game settings {}", event.getMinecraftSupplier().get().options);
    }

    private void enqueueIMC(final InterModEnqueueEvent event)
    {
        // some example code to dispatch IMC to another mod
        InterModComms.sendTo("hollowknightmod", "helloworld", () -> { LOGGER.info("Hello world from the MDK"); return "Hello world";});
    }

    private void processIMC(final InterModProcessEvent event)
    {
        // some example code to receive and process InterModComms from other mods
        LOGGER.info("Got IMC {}", event.getIMCStream().
                map(m->m.getMessageSupplier().get()).
                collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
    // You can use SubscribeEvent and let the Event Bus discover methods to call
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onServerStarting(FMLServerStartingEvent event) {
        // do something when the server starts
        LOGGER.info("HELLO from server starting");
    }

    // You can use EventBusSubscriber to automatically subscribe events on the contained class (this is subscribing to the MOD
    // Event bus for receiving Registry Events)
    @Mod.EventBusSubscriber(bus=Mod.EventBusSubscriber.Bus.MOD)
    public static class RegistryEvents {
        @SubscribeEvent
        public static void onBlocksRegistry(final RegistryEvent.Register<Block> blockRegistryEvent) {
            // register a new block here
            LOGGER.info("HELLO from Register Block");
        }
    }
}
```

Error Log:

A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Render thread
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraftforge.eventbus.EventBus.registerListener(EventBus.java:145) ~[eventbus-4.0.0.jar:?] {}
-- MOD hollowknightmod --
Details:
    Mod File: main
    Failure message: Hollow Knight Mod (hollowknightmod) encountered an error during the sided_setup event phase
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method public static void com.example.hollowknightmod.PlayerScaleHandler.onRenderPlayer(net.minecraftforge.client.event.RenderPlayerEvent$Pre) has @SubscribeEvent annotation, but takes an argument that is not a subtype of the base type interface net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.IModBusEvent: class net.minecraftforge.client.event.RenderPlayerEvent$Pre
    Mod Version: NONE
    Mod Issue URL: NOT PROVIDED
    Exception message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method public static void com.example.hollowknightmod.PlayerScaleHandler.onRenderPlayer(net.minecraftforge.client.event.RenderPlayerEvent$Pre) has @SubscribeEvent annotation, but takes an argument that is not a subtype of the base type interface net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.IModBusEvent: class net.minecraftforge.client.event.RenderPlayerEvent$Pre
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraftforge.eventbus.EventBus.registerListener(EventBus.java:145) ~[eventbus-4.0.0.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.eventbus.EventBus.lambda$registerClass$2(EventBus.java:78) ~[eventbus-4.0.0.jar:?] {}
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[?:1.8.0_372-372] {}
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[?:1.8.0_372-372] {}
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[?:1.8.0_372-372] {}
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[?:1.8.0_372-372] {}
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[?:1.8.0_372-372] {}
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[?:1.8.0_372-372] {}
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[?:1.8.0_372-372] {}
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[?:1.8.0_372-372] {}
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_372-372] {}
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485) ~[?:1.8.0_372-372] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.eventbus.EventBus.registerClass(EventBus.java:78) ~[eventbus-4.0.0.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.eventbus.EventBus.register(EventBus.java:118) ~[eventbus-4.0.0.jar:?] {}
    at com.example.hollowknightmod.HollowKnightMod.doClientStuff(HollowKnightMod.java:64) ~[main/:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.eventbus.EventBus.doCastFilter(EventBus.java:247) ~[eventbus-4.0.0.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.eventbus.EventBus.lambda$addListener$11(EventBus.java:239) ~[eventbus-4.0.0.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:302) ~[eventbus-4.0.0.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:283) ~[eventbus-4.0.0.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLModContainer.acceptEvent(FMLModContainer.java:120) ~[forge:36.2] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModContainer.lambda$buildTransitionHandler$4(ModContainer.java:121) ~[forge:?] {re:classloading}
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1640) ~[?:1.8.0_372-372] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1632) ~[?:1.8.0_372-372] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) ~[?:1.8.0_372-372] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056) ~[?:1.8.0_372-372] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692) ~[?:1.8.0_372-372] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175) ~[?:1.8.0_372-372] {}
```

My plan is that from the beginning of the game the player has the size of a block, I didn't expect this to be so difficult